# How to join a multiple foreign key within the foreign key in a single table in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have Waybill Table in which the joborderID is foreign key of Joborder Table in joborder Table there is FleetTypeID which is the ForeignKey of FleetTypeID and in FleetType Table there are two more foreign key ItemsID and FleetTypeItemsID

The problem is I want to retrieve joborder_table data in waybill_table but the foreign keys in joborder_table are not joining

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
        FTI.FleetTypeItem  Fleet_Items, 
        I.ItemsName  Items, 
        P.Payment, 
        C.CityName  City
 FROM FleetTypeItemTbl FTI,
      PaymentTbl PAY
   INNER JOIN FleetTypeTbl FT ON FTI.FleetTypeItemID = FT.FleetTypeItemID
   INNER JOIN ItemsTbl I  ON I.ItemsID = FT.ItemsID
   inner join PaymentCityAllocation PC on PAY.PaymentID = PC.PaymentID
   inner join CityTbl CT on CT.CityID = PC.CityID
   inner join JoborderTbl j on FT.FleetTypeID = j.FleetTypeID
   inner join WaybillTbl w on j.JoborderID = w.JoborderID
 where ft.Active = 1
```

Comment: Without looking at the data it is hard to tell what is the problem can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: Did you mean to `crossjoin` `FleetTypeItemTbl` to `PaymentTbl`? You're selecting `P.Payment`, did you mean `PAY.Payment`?

Comment: moreover,you should always explain the relationship with diagram.

Comment: This query wont even compile. It will return error "P.Payment not found"

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in the code. Use `cross join`

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    FTI.FleetTypeItem  Fleet_Items, 
    I.ItemsName  Items, 
    P.Payment, 
    C.CityName  City
 FROM FleetTypeItemTbl FTI
    cross  join PaymentTbl PAY 
    INNER JOIN FleetTypeTbl FT ON FTI.FleetTypeItemID = FT.FleetTypeItemID
    INNER JOIN ItemsTbl I  ON I.ItemsID = FT.ItemsID
    inner join PaymentCityAllocation PC on PAY.PaymentID = PC.PaymentID
    inner join CityTbl CT on CT.CityID = PC.CityID
    inner join JoborderTbl j on FT.FleetTypeID = j.FleetTypeID
    inner join WaybillTbl w on j.JoborderID = w.JoborderID
```